# Symfony - ClassNotFoundException in app_dev.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, composer-php

In my local version works normally, but when I put on the server, has this problem! Please help.

**ERROR**

> ClassNotFoundException in app_dev.php line 27:
>   Attempted to load class "AppKernel" from the global namespace.
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\app\AppKernel" or "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Tests\Functional\app\AppKernel"?

My app_dev.php :

```
<?php

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

    // If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
    // read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
    //umask(0000);

    // This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
    // Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
    ) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
    }

    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
    Debug::enable();

    require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My AppKernel.php

```
        <?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new UserBundle\UserBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new Lunetics\LocaleBundle\LuneticsLocaleBundle(),
            # New reference upload
            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            new FM\ElfinderBundle\FMElfinderBundle(),
            new Sonata\SeoBundle\SonataSeoBundle(),
            # Routing translate
            #new BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

My autoload.php:

```
    <?php
    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
    use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

    /**
    * @var ClassLoader $loader
    */
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

    return $loader;
```

My composer.json:

```
    {
"name": "pedrorossi/dragoes.das.gerais",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "*",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "1.1.4",
    "lunetics/locale-bundle": "^2.4",
    "besimple/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that there's a whitespace at the beginning of your AppKernel file ?

Comment: Also, you are certainly executing PHPUnit on your server, and therefore you should also check your `app/phpunit.xml.dist` file to be sure the `Kernel` information is well configured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using your app/boostrap.php.cache file as the autoload, please change the following line

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

to

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

Please also make sure that the following code exists in your composer.json file

```
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
```